# Data Assignment and Scope Problem in Python

Tags: python, sorting, scope

I have run into a very frustrating problem in Python. I am trying to make a sorting algorithm that works like so:

1. I read one variable from a list
2. I check how many variables have a lower value than that variable and assign that to a place variable
3. The current variable is put in its place
4. continue to the next variable and repeat

The problem is that the dummy variable automatically resets to zero after being incremented. I can't do step by step program running, so figuring out what's wrong is very difficult.

I have very little experience with python, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# sorting algorithm
theList = [9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, -1]
def order(n):
    a = 0
    m = n
    print(n)
    print(m)
    while a < len(n):
        b = 0
        c = 0 #this is where the problem is
        while b < len(n):
            if n[b] < n[a]:
                c += 1 # after this if statement isn't true, c reverts to zero
            print(c)
            b += 1
        #I think I should be able to put m[c] = n[a], but this doesn't work
        a += 1
    print(n)
    print(m)
order(theList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = n
```

Does not create a new list. It just maps the name `m` to the same list that `n` points to. So when you do `m[c] = n[a]` the original list also changes - hence the unexpected behaviour.

Try:

```
def order(n):
    a = 0
    m = n[:] # create copy
    print(n)
    print(m)
    while a < len(n):
        b = 0
        c = 0
        while b < len(n):
            if n[b] < n[a]:
                c += 1
            print(c)
            b += 1
        m[c] = n[a] # assign in output
        a += 1
    print(n)
    print(m)
```

This does create a copy & seems to solve the issue:

```
...
[9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, -1]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

PS: sorting should not require a copy of the list to be made. There are better algorithms that can modify the list in-place.